# Evaluating a string against a pattern with RegExp in Flutter

Tags: regex, validation, flutter

I'm trying to evaluate a string against a set list of parameters with RegExp in Flutter. For example, the string must contain at least:

- One capital letter
- One lowercase letter
- One number from 0-9
- One special character, such as $ or !

This is basically for a password entry field of an application. I have set things up, firstly using `validateStructure` as follows:

```
abstract class PasswordValidator {
  bool validateStructure(String value);
}
```

Then, I have used the `RegExp` function as follows:

```
class PasswordValidatorSpecial implements PasswordValidator {
  bool validateStructure(String value) {
    String pattern =
        r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~£]).{8,}$';
    RegExp regEx = new RegExp(pattern);
    return regEx.hasMatch(value);
  }
}
```

This does work well, in a sense that when I pass a string/password through it, it does tell me if at least one of the criteria is not met. However, what I would like to do is for the output to be more specific, telling me which of those criteria isn't met.

For example, if the password were to have everything but a number (from 0-9) I would want to be able to get the output to specifically say that a number is missing, but everything else is present.

How would I adapt my code to be able to do that? I thought perhaps by using conditional 'if' statement, although I don't know how that would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's right, you can use [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to check your RegExp, separate each part and use them separately to have a custom error. Also instead of return a bool value, you can return a String value, such as the following function:

```
String validateStructure(String value) {
    String patternUpperCaseCharacters = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])';
    String patternLowerCaseCharacters = r'^(?=.*?[a-z])';
    String patternNumbers = r'^(?=.*?[0-9])';
    String patternSpecialCharacters = r'^(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~£])';

    RegExp regEx = new RegExp(patternUpperCaseCharacters);
    if (regEx.hasMatch(value)) {
      regEx = new RegExp(patternLowerCaseCharacters);
      if (regEx.hasMatch(value)) {
        return "More errors";
      } else {
        return "You need at least one lowercase letter";
      }
    } else {
      return "You need at least one capital letter";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I actually really like that, thanks! It is quite easy to understand, when it shows the errors sequentially, so it doesn't just show them all at once. The email form I have created uses `TextField()` with a `decoration` field, that has `errorText` as a parameter. To allow the output string of the `validateStructure` function to be called here (to be shown under the cell), would I simply write `errorText: validateStructure`? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: There are many ways to do that, personally I like to use `Streams` and `setState` for form validations, I imagine that you are using the second one, so you can call the `validateStructure` function in the `onChanged` parameter of your TextField, and update the state in the corresponding place.  And to use the Streams please check the point 4 of Form Validations in this article: https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/12/reactive-programming---streams---bloc---practical-use-cases/

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the link. I appreciate it. I'll give it a go today and see how far I get.